# Разделение frontend & backend

Tags: php, nginx

Во время настройки nginx столкнулся с такой проблемой, что после настройки стили в директории admin не подключается.
вот таким образом я делаю настройку.

```
server {
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    root /home/server/php/src;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

        location ~ ^/static/.+\.php(/|$) {
            deny all;
        }
    }

    location ~* \.(htaccess|htpasswd|svn|git) {
        deny all;
    }

    location /admin {
        #try_files $uri /admin/index.php$is_args$args;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.php$is_args$args;

        location ~ ^/admin/assets/.+\.php(/|$) {
            deny all;
        } 
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(js|css|ttf|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|tar|bz2|pdf|doc|docx|rtf|xls|ppt|mp3|public|assets|images|fonts|plugins|static)$ {
        #access_log off;
        #log_not_found off;
        #expires 3d; # кеширование статики 3 дня
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    #error_page 404 /404.html;

    location ~ ^/assets/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* /\. {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "error_log=/var/log/nginx/application_php_errors.log";
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: Какие стили? Куда не подключаются? Как подключаете?

Comment: Есть админка там есть стили, js, images  для админпанели. После настройки на nginx не работают они. Пытаюсь на прямую в браузере открыть, пишет 404 ошибку

Comment: Это всё ни о чем, конкретные админки и конкретные ссылки в студию